# Split PHP array for a grid layout

Tags: php, css, arrays

I need to write a PHP function to split an array into multiple arrays to accommodate it into a  grid layout. In simplified terms, here's what I need to achieve:

Source data array:

```
$table = array(
'a','b','c','d',
'e','f','g','h',
'i','j','k','l',
'm','n','o','p',
'q','r','s','t',
'u','v','w','x',
'y','z');
```

I need to create a function, which takes this array an an input and also takes grid details as input (as mentioned below) and splits the array. For example:

```
grid_split($table, 1, 4); // 1st of 4 grid columns
```

Should return:

```
array('a','e','i','m','q','u','y');
```

and,

```
grid_split($table, 2, 4); // 2nd of 4 grid columns
```

Should return:

```
array('b','f','j','n','r','v','z');
```

similarly this,

```
grid_split($table, 1, 3); // 1st of 3 grid columns
```

Should return:

```
array('a','d','g','j','m','p','s','v','y');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>You could use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function.</del>

```
function grid_split($arr, $n, $grids) {
  $limit = count($arr) / $grids;
  return array_slice($arr, ($n - 1) * $limit, $limit);
}
```

***Update:*** miss reading your question, the below is what you want.

```
function grid_split($arr, $n, $grids) {
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % $grids === $n - 1) {
      $ret[] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: `grid_split($table, 1, 4)` returns `Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f )` expected is `Array ( [0] => a [1] => e [2] => i [3] => m [4] => q [5] => u [6] => y )`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a run-of-the-mill for loop:

```
for($i = $n - 1, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i += $grids) {
    $ret[] = $arr[$i];
}
```